# Propagating production of chromic acid consuming only Cr$_2$O$_3$ & H$_2$O$_2$

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I only have access to a small amount of pure chromic acid & I need to produce more. On the other hand, what I have is ample $\ce{Cr2O3}$.

Would adding $\ce{Cr2O3}$ powder to chromic acid & $\ce{H2O2}$ & heating it up convert all the $\ce{Cr2O3}$ to chromic acid?

1.) $\ce{Cr2O3 + 9H2O + 6H+ -> 2[Cr(H2O)6]^{3+}}$

2.) $\ce{[Cr(H2O)6]^{3+} + 3H2O2 -> CrO3 + 9H2O}$

3.) $\ce{CrO3 + H2O <=> H2CrO4}$

Then the resulting $\ce{H2CrO4}$ will propagate reaction back to (1), consuming only $\ce{Cr2O3}$ & $\ce{H2O2}$.

Looks to like it could work. Do you guys think this needs special apparatus for applying high pressure or high heat?